# Guard not getting updates on cifs system

Tags: ruby, guard, cifs

I'm trying to use guard to trigger builds but I can't get it to work. I have the following in my guard file, the last of which I assume should cause updates to be triggered all the time and be printing stuff to the screen:

```
guard 'rails', :host => '0.0.0.0' do
  watch('Gemfile.lock')
  watch(%r{^(config|lib)/.*})
  watch(%r{.*}){puts "something changed"}
end
```

however nothing I change seems to do anything. The only thing I can think of is that this is a cifs filesystem, and I'm not sure how the file updates work on that. Is there anything I can do to look into this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that cifs doesn't have a lot of the same events, so you need to run guard with the poll option: `bundle exec guard -p`